Unable to Access Camera or Gallery on iOS Using Flutter
Hello Flutter Community,
I am experiencing an issue with my Flutter app where I am unable to access the camera or gallery on iOS devices. The same functionality is working fine on Android. The app does not crash nor shows any error messages when I attempt to access these features; it simply does not respond to the permission request or the action to pick an image.
Environment:
Flutter version: 3.19.5
permission_handler version: 11.3.1
iOS version: 17
Code Implementation:
Permission Request:
Future<void> requestPermission() async {
  PermissionStatus status = await Permission.camera.status;
  if (!status.isGranted) {
    await Permission.camera.request();
  }
  status = await Permission.photos.status;
  if (!status.isGranted) {
    await Permission.photos.request();
  }
}

Image Picking:
void pickImage() async {
  final pickedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  if (pickedImage != null) {
    // Process image
  }
}


Info.Plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>Five Digtis Solution</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>five_digtis_solution</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen</string>
        <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
        <string>Main</string>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Our app needs access to your photo library to pick images.</string>
        <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Our app needs access to your photo library to save images.</string>
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Our app needs access to your camera to take photos.</string>
        <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>



Issue Description:
When I trigger the action to pick an image, there are no errors logged in the console, and no permissions dialog is shown on iOS. The button press does not result in any visible action or log output.
Troubleshooting Done:

Confirmed entries in Info.plist for camera and photo library access.
Checked console logs via Xcode, no relevant errors displayed.
Tested on multiple iOS devices.
Ran flutter clean and rebuilt the app.
Permissions request code executes, but doesn't seem to prompt on iOS.

Questions:

Could there be an issue with how permissions are handled specifically on iOS with Flutter?
Is there a known issue with permission_handler or ImagePicker on certain iOS versions?
Any suggestions on additional debugging steps or configurations I might be missing?


what value does the permission_handler return?
